# Mismanaged transaction stack for database routers using SQLAlchemy to dispatch between write master & read replicas

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

We need to route our database requests to either a writer master database or a set of read replicas.

We found a [blog post](https://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/) by Mike Bayer suggesting how to do so using SQLAlchemy. We replicated with a few changes but unfortunately, we have one test out of a few hundreds interacting with the test that fail, complaining about improper transaction setup.

First, the code we use to replicate:

```
class RoutingSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SQLAlchemy.__init__(self, use_native_unicode=True, session_options=None,
                            query_class=BaseQuery, model_class=Model,
                            *args, **kwargs)
        self.session.using_bind = lambda s: self.session().using_bind(s)

    def create_scoped_session(self, options=None):
        if options is None:
            options = {}
        scopefunc = options.pop("scopefunc", _app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__)
        options.setdefault("query_cls", BaseQuery)
        return orm.scoped_session(
            partial(ExplicitRoutingSession, self, **options), scopefunc=scopefunc
        )


class RoutingSession(SignallingSession):

    _name = None

    def __init__(self, db, autocommit=False, autoflush=True, **options):
        self.app = db.get_app()
        self.db = db
        self._model_changes = {}
        options.setdefault("query_cls", BaseQuery)
        orm.Session.__init__(
            self, autocommit=autocommit, autoflush=autoflush,
            bind=db.engine,
            binds=db.get_binds(self.app), **options)

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        try:
            state = get_state(self.app)
        except (AssertionError, AttributeError, TypeError) as err:
            current_app.logger.error(
                "cant get configuration. default bind. Error:" + err)
            return orm.Session.get_bind(self, mapper, clause)

        if state is None or not self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS']:
            if not self.app.debug:
                current_app.logger.debug("Connecting -> DEFAULT")
            return orm.Session.get_bind(self, mapper, clause)

        return self.route(state, mapper, clause)

    @abstractmethod
    def route(self, state, mapper=None, clause=None):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def using_bind(self, name):
        pass


class ExplicitRoutingSession(RoutingSession):

    def __init__(self, db, autocommit=False, autoflush=True, **options):
        RoutingSession.__init__(
            self, db, autocommit=autocommit, autoflush=autoflush, **options)

    def route(self, state, mapper=None, clause=None):
        # Use the explicit name if present
        if self._name:
            self.app.logger.debug(f"Connecting -> ${self._name}")
            engine = state.db.get_engine(self.app, bind=self._name)
            # self._name = None
            return engine
        # Everything else goes to the writer engine
        else:
            current_app.logger.debug("Connecting -> WRITER")
            engine = state.db.get_engine(self.app, bind='writer')
            # self._name = None
            return engine

    def using_bind(self, name):
        s = ExplicitRoutingSession(self.db)
        vars(s).update(vars(self))
        s._name = name
        return s
```

Then, when running one of our test, we get the failure below. It seems making a http call (using a Flask test client:

```
client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'test'>>
notify_db = <RoutingSQLAlchemy engine=postgres://postgres:***@localhost:5432/notification_api_master>
notify_db_session = <RoutingSQLAlchemy engine=postgres://postgres:***@localhost:5432/notification_api_master>
sample_api_key = <ApiKey d1baf71c-1005-4f11-9b6f-5b765866b74d>
sample_notification = <Notification 7dec469a-9de4-47f8-986a-d935d467e239>

    def test_normal_api_key_returns_notifications_created_from_jobs_and_from_api(
        client,
        notify_db,
        notify_db_session,
        sample_api_key,
        sample_notification
    ):
        api_notification = create_sample_notification(
            notify_db,
            notify_db_session,
            api_key=sample_api_key
        )
        api_notification.job = None
    
        headers = _create_auth_header_from_key(sample_api_key)
    
        # from app import db
        # db.session.close()
        # db.session.begin()
    
>       response = client.get(
            path='/notifications',
            headers=headers)

tests/app/notifications/test_rest.py:179: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1006: in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/testing.py:222: in open
    return Client.open(
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:970: in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:861: in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1096: in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:2464: in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notifications_utils/request_helper.py:74: in __call__
    return self.app(environ, rewrite_response_headers)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:2450: in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:1867: in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39: in reraise
    raise value
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:2447: in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:1952: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:1821: in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39: in reraise
    raise value
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:1948: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py:2242: in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
app/authentication/auth.py:87: in requires_auth
    service = dao_fetch_service_by_id_with_api_keys(client)
app/dao/services_dao.py:210: in dao_fetch_service_by_id_with_api_keys
    return query.one()
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3490: in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3459: in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3534: in __iter__
    self.session._autoflush()
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:1618: in _autoflush
    self.flush()
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2536: in flush
    self._flush(objects)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2678: in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:82: in __exit__
    compat.raise_(value, with_traceback=traceback)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:182: in raise_
    raise exception
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2678: in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:524: in rollback
    for subtransaction in stx._iterate_self_and_parents(upto=self):
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x113a2caf0>
upto = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x115a09850>

    def _iterate_self_and_parents(self, upto=None):
    
        current = self
        result = ()
        while current:
            result += (current,)
            if current._parent is upto:
                break
            elif current._parent is None:
>               raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
                    "Transaction %s is not on the active transaction list"
                    % (upto)
                )
E               sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Transaction <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x115a09850> is not on the active transaction list

../../.virtualenvs/api-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:329: InvalidRequestError
```

Strangely enough, adding an additional `db.session.commit()` call in the test prior to the HTTP call make the test green.

What would be the likely culprit of this behaviour? Previous code that didn't commit and hence the transaction stack got corrupted somehow?

Notes:

- We are also using flask-sqlalchemy.
- This is from an open source notification platform and [you can browse the code/branch yourself](https://github.com/cds-snc/notification-api/blob/feat/read-replicas/app/dbsetup.py).
- The error indicates the transaction is not sitting in the active transaction list. It is slightly incorrect. Having debugged the code, there is a check for verifying the session transaction is a child of the current session transaction (on top of my head -- might be incorrect on details). It is not but the relationship is reversed: it's actually a parent (or vice versa -- but it's present in the current instances).
- There is a proper `commit` on the database prior to make the HTTP call (per my assumption on code I read), somehow, it needs an extra one to make the test properly pass.