# Reusing a single session for routing connections with SQLAlchemy between master & read replicas

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

We needed to route our database requests to either a writer master database or a set of read replicas.

We found a [blog post](https://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/) by Mike Bayer suggesting how to do so using SQLAlchemy. We replicated the solution but that did not work out with our existing tests [due to various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66019454/mismanaged-transaction-stack-for-database-routers-using-sqlalchemy-to-dispatch-b).

We went on with the following below. This will reuse one session rather than creating new ones that will stack altogether:

```
class ExplicitRoutingSession(SignallingSession):

    _name = None

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        # If reader and writer binds are not configured,
        # connect using the default SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
        if not self.binds_setup:
            return super().get_bind(mapper, clause)

        return self.load_balance(mapper, clause)

    def load_balance(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        # Use the explicit name if present
        if self._name and not self._flushing:
            bind = self._name
            self._name = None
            self.app.logger.debug(f"Connecting -> {bind}")
            return get_state(self.app).db.get_engine(self.app, bind=bind)

        # Everything else goes to the writer engine
        else:
            self.app.logger.debug("Connecting -> writer")
            return get_state(self.app).db.get_engine(self.app, bind='writer')

    def using_bind(self, name):
        self._name = name
        return self

    @cached_property
    def binds_setup(self):
        binds = self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] or {}
        return all([k in binds for k in ['reader', 'writer']])
```

So far it works good for us. We assume we might lose some functionality such as db save points by not having stacked sessions... but we'd like to know if there are stability and unforeseen risks other than losing features with such an approach?

Notes:

- We are also using flask-sqlalchemy.
- This is from an open source notification platform and [you can browse the code/branch yourself](https://github.com/cds-snc/notification-api/pull/1219/files).